# Embedded Ignite with spring never calls custom SegmentationResolver

Tags: spring, tomcat, ignite

I try to manage network segmentation in a Ignite cluster that is embedded in a tomcat webapp. I create a custom segmentationResolver that ping database server.

So I configure Ignite with spring context

```
<beans:bean id="segmentationResolver" class="my.cluster.JdbcPingSegmentationResolver"/>
<beans:bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <beans:property name="gridLogger">
        <beans:bean class="org.apache.ignite.logger.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"/>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="workDirectory" value="#{systemProperties[igniteTmpDir]}"/>
    <beans:property name="segmentationResolvers" ref="segmentationResolver" />
    <beans:property name="segmentCheckFrequency" value="10000" />
    <beans:property name="segmentationPolicy" value="NOOP" />
    <beans:property name="waitForSegmentOnStart" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="communicationSpi">....
```

Constructor of my JdbcPingSegmentationResolver is call by spring but its method *isValidSegment()* is never calls. Even if I start / stop another Ignite node (it has to be called when cluster topology change).

```
 @Override
    public boolean isValidSegment() throws IgniteCheckedException {
        var reachable = false;
        try {
            Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping " + hostname);
            //0 - normal termination
            reachable = exec.waitFor(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.error("segmentation network : {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        LOGGER.debug("check segmentation network status : {}", reachable);
        return reachable;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segmentation resolvers are called by a `GridSegmentationProcessor`. The default processor is `org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.segmentation.os.GridOsSegmentationProcessor` which is noop in fact. **GridGain Enterprise Edition** (it's a vendor-supported delivery of Apache Ignite) specifies a processor that handles resolvers properly.

I believe that the machinery that's being called on topology changes (node left, join etc) is [topology validator](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/TopologyValidator.html).

Comment: OK I read that https://www.bugdbug.com/post/how-to-handle-network-segmentation-in-apache-ignite, so I need to use spi incantation and plugin... I was hoping that with spring I can avoid that.